# Login, but then, error

Tags: android, actionscript-3, google-play-services, google-play-games

I'm developing an app using Flash CC. I'm using the Google Play Services to login the people in the App, but I have a problem.

When I install the App, I have to login. When I'm logged in, I don't have problems. If I close the app and then I open again the game,  says that I'm not logged in. So, I click login, I log in but then I recive the SIGN_IN_FAILS error. In the code, first I check if the user is logged in and if is not logged in, I show the Log In button. But what happens with the people who has connected before? I have an "else" telling that if he is already logged in, he can 'Continue'. But always says that I'm not logged and I have to log in! But if I log in another time I get the error!

PS. I'm using freshplanet/laurentiu ANE/library.

** EDIT **

CODE:

```
import com.freshplanet.ane.AirGooglePlayGames.AirGooglePlayGames;
import com.freshplanet.ane.AirGooglePlayGames.AirGooglePlayGamesEvent;
import com.laurentiu.ane.AirGooglePlayServices.AirGooglePlayServices;

var airGooglePlayGames: AirGooglePlayGames = AirGooglePlayGames.getInstance();

airGooglePlayGames.addEventListener(AirGooglePlayGamesEvent.ON_SIGN_IN_SUCCESS, onSignInSuccess);
airGooglePlayGames.addEventListener(AirGooglePlayGamesEvent.ON_SIGN_OUT_SUCCESS, onSignOutSuccess);
airGooglePlayGames.addEventListener(AirGooglePlayGamesEvent.ON_SIGN_IN_FAIL, onSignInFail);

this.checkeStatus();
button_login.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, googleSignIn);
btn_out.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, googleSignOut);
btn_out.visible = false;
button_login.visible = false;

function googleSignIn(e: MouseEvent = null): void {
AirGooglePlayGames.getInstance().signIn();
}
function checkeStatus() {
if (!AirGooglePlayGames.getInstance().isSignedIn()) {
    // Always stay here when I reopen the app
    btn_out.visible = false;
    button_login.visible = true;
} else {
    // I never arrive here
    texto.text = "PLAYERID: " +     AirGooglePlayGames.getInstance().getActivePlayerID();
    loadingBar.gotoAndStop(2);
    button_login.visible = false;
    btn_out.visible = true;
}
}
function onSignInSuccess(e: AirGooglePlayGamesEvent): void {
// I only arrive here if is the first time I open the app and login for first time
texto.text = "PLAYERID: " +     AirGooglePlayGames.getInstance().getActivePlayerID();
loadingBar.gotoAndStop(2);
button_login.visible = false;
btn_out.visible = true;
}
function onSignOutSuccess(e: AirGooglePlayGamesEvent): void {
texto.text = "SIGN OUT OKAY!";
loadingBar.gotoAndStop(1);
button_login.visible = true;
btn_out.visible = false;
}
function onSignInFail(e: AirGooglePlayGamesEvent): void {
texto.text = "SING IN FAIL: " + e;
loadingBar.gotoAndStop(1);
button_login.visible = true;
btn_out.visible = false;
}
function googleSignOut(e: AirGooglePlayGamesEvent): void {
texto.text = "SIGN OUT PROGRESS";
airGooglePlayGames.signOut();
loadingBar.gotoAndStop(1);
button_login.visible = true;
btn_out.visible = false;
}
```

Any idea what could happen?

Comment: I use the login in frame 2, the frame 1 is just a "loader" frame. I put the code in my question. @Aaron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things that might help:

I think your stuff at the top should be in a constructor function. For this type of code, with event listeners, you might be much better off making an external .as3 file and attach to a document class or movieClip base class, than putting the code in the timeline, as I think your code might not always be available as you move around??

And I notice you do:

> this.checkeStatus();

Right away, which might do this:

```
btn_out.visible = false;
button_login.visible = true;
```

Or it might do this:

```
button_login.visible = false;
btn_out.visible = true;
```

But I think it doesn't matter because right after that, you return to the line under **this.checkeStatus()**, and get this:

```
btn_out.visible = false;
button_login.visible = false;
```

So no matter what happened with **this.checkeStatus()**, you end up with both buttons turned off, no? So maybe try moving `this.checkeStatus();` down to the bottom of the constructor function so it goes last.

It might be more compact and less confusing to break off all these repeating visible = false / true lines into their own function like:

```
private function setStatusButtonsVisible(status:Boolean){
    button_login.visible = status;
    btn_out.visible = !status;
    if (status){
        loadingBar.gotoAndStop(2);
    }else{
        loadingBar.gotoAndStop(1);
    }
}
```

Since in all cases but the first you're toggling the 2nd to be the opposite of the first.